# Estimating the median age of first marriage although some people never marry

Tags: confidence-interval, bootstrap, median

Suppose that I want to estimate the median value of the age that people in some country marry for the first time. My samples could look something like this:

[21, 20, Never married, 38, 24, 30, Never married, 22, 20, 32, 26, 29]

As some people never marry, I don't think it's meaningful to find the mean value of the underlying distribution, so I am interested in the median instead. How do I estimate the median value of the distribution that those samples come from with a confidence interval using bootstrapping? Also, in the case that the majority of my samples contained people that never married, then the median would be "Never married", but what kind of a confidence interval would that give me?

Comment: Don't confuse "never married" with "not married yet". Do you know the age of the people who are coded as "never married"? If you don't you should omit those people from the sample, and then the mean is appropriate to look at.

Comment: Why not just estimate the mean value of the age that people marry for the first time given that they marry at all?  That gets rid of all the people who don't marry!  If you want to include the supplemental information that $x%$ of the population don't marry, that would cover all the information.

Comment: @AdamO Let's assume that the data is from the 19th century and those people died before marrying.

Comment: This sounds like a perfect application of Kaplan-Meier estimation (only change "dying" to "got married"), which provides for individuals not as yet observed to marry (whether or not they ever do) to contribute to risk of getting married in each time period, and also for estimation of median time to marry. Kaplan, E. L. and Meier, P. (1958). [Nonparametric estimation from incomplete observations](https://web.stanford.edu/~lutian/coursepdf/KMpaper.pdf). *Journal of the American Statistical Association*, 53(2):457–481. Of course more modern discrete-time event history models could also be used.

Comment: @Sid you said yourself you want to estimate the "age of first marriage". If you're truly never married, then your data do not matter for that calculation. You should of course present proportions who never married.

Comment: @AdamO  If you are never married then you **still contribute to the denominator at risk of marrying while you are observed**

Comment: @Alexis indeed if the design is cross sectional and "never married" means "not married yet" and OP knows the ages, he can use KM curves, and the median is an unbiased estimator whereas the mean is biased when omitting censoring events. But there is not enough detail to say as much based on the rather limited problem description.

Comment: @Alexis you would need to know the age of death

Comment: @AdamO Not sure what you mean by "cross-sectional". K-M is more or less *prima facie* a longitudinal analysis. (Although, the OP is rather vague about the precise nature of the data available to them :).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72885/discussion-between-adamo-and-alexis).

Comment: @AdamO: "But there is not enough detail to say as much based on the rather limited problem description." Let me know what more description you need. I am interested in the data of the whole population, not just those who  got married before dying, so just including those who did get married does not work for me.

Comment: One of the points, Sid, is that you are not interested in all people. Your inquiry is about age at first marriage and therefore does not concern people who never marry. If you follow a group of individuals from birth to death you can identify those who marry and study those ages. If you select a group of individuals *at this moment* (a cross section), then you don't know which of the unmarried ones will eventually marry. All you know is that *if* they marry, they will be older than they are now. You need to account for this partial information. Calling them "never married" is inadequate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are quite right to note that *not everyone gets married*. This points to the need for, and the power of the statistical concept of *censoring*, meaning that we have only partial information on a subject. More specifically, we are talking about *left-censoring* meaning that we observe them for a time, and then we do not know what happens afterward. In your case, during the entire time they were observed, some individuals *did not* get married. So what to do with this information? Well, during the time when they were observed *any* unmarried individual in your data was *at risk* of getting married, so they should contribute to the denominator in estimating risk of marrying at a given point in time, and to any cumulative measure of risk of marrying *by* a certain point in time.

These issues point squarely to *event history analysis* (which has a history of being termed "survival analysis" since it was developed originally for actuarial tables of life expectancy). Kaplan & Meier's estimator was, I believe, the first modeling approach to try and answer *whether and when an event will occur* along these lines. The Kaplan-Meier curve describes not experiencing even by a particular time, by graphing the estimated survival function $\hat{S}(t)$ vs. time. The survival function itself is the cumulative product of complements of the hazard function, $\hat{h}(t)$, which describes the probability of experiencing the event at time $t$. The median survival time—the last time at which half the subjects at risk experienced marriage and half did not—is represented on such curves.

More generalized discrete-time event history models have been developed (e.g., logit hazard, probit hazard, complementary log-log hazard, etc.), since the Kaplan-Meier estimator. There are, in addition, generalized continuous time event history models (e.g., Cox proportional hazards model, etc.). (Different categories of event history model will use different nomenclature... for example I believe the estimated hazard function I described above has quite a different meaning in, for example, competing risks models and Cox proportional hazards models.)

There are, naturally, a host of nuances one must think about when performing these kinds of analysis: the meaning of a unit of time, the beginning of time, time- and age-related selection biases, etc.

**References**

Kaplan, E. L. and Meier, P. (1958). [Nonparametric estimation from incomplete observations](https://web.stanford.edu/~lutian/coursepdf/KMpaper.pdf). *Journal of the American Statistical Association*, 53(2):457–481.

Singer, J. D. and Willett, J. B. (2003). *Applied Longitudinal Data Analysis: Modeling change and event occurrence*. Oxford University Press, New York, NY.